# How to call customized template page before hitting 404 in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

In Wordpress, I need to call my own page when there are no pages available. This should happen before hitting a 404 page. How can I customise Wordpress to have this behaviour?

Comment: Sorry about that! I answered for Django, not WordPress. Must be time for a beer.

Answer (score 0):

That has nothing to do with Wordpress or Django. ;-)

```
<?php
   header("Status: 301 Moved Permanently");
   header("Location:/");
?>
```

Input the URL you prefer to be relocate for "Location:". In my case it will relocate to the root-page.

EDIT:
You can make your special template then create a page and set your special template as page template or you can simple create a static html page. In both cases you have then to set "Location:" to the URL of your 404-page.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Forgot to say that the whole think should be in your 404.php!

Comment: yes. this should not happend. I have used some wordpress cretaed pages, also i need to access some other external content (includes meta title and keyword and description) by using webservice call.

As of now, i make the external function call in header if its is_404(){ // call func }. but this is the not a good solution. because request goes to 404 page and displayed the page.

so i need to call external pages without using 404 request